# No resource found that matches the given name dialogCornerRadius

Tags: android, react-native

```
Failed to generate resource table for split ''
/Users/me/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-28.0.0.aar/5350756d4feccc54333994727594933b/res/values-v28/values-v28.xml:5:5-8:13: AAPT: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'dialogCornerRadius' with value '?android:attr/dialogCornerRadius').
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to fix this issue. It's only happening when I build the release version of my app. Below are the versions I'm currently using.

```
implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0"
compileSdkVersion 28
buildToolsVersion "28.0.0"
```

Comment: Wow, this is the exact same issue as I got, and the (finally) first time I've found someone else on the web with the same. Can't find any issue or question whit the same problem. It might be useful to add some additional information of the response of your console (where does the build fail?). Did you already manage to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I am going to put an answer on this (I commented 15 minutes ago), because I have a (dirty) solution. You probably have a `release` and `releaseStaging` right? `assembleRelease` will fail while `assembleReleaseStaging` is passing. I've added a `assembleReleaseProduction` buildType which looks like this:

```
    buildTypes {
        debug {
          applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
          buildConfigField "String", "CODEPUSH_KEY", "\"\""
        }
        releaseStaging {
          applicationIdSuffix ".staging"
          matchingFallbacks = ['release', 'debug']
          signingConfig signingConfigs.staging
          buildConfigField "String", "CODEPUSH_KEY", "\"wont-give-it\""     

          minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
          proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro" 
        }
        releaseProduction {
          matchingFallbacks = ['release']
          signingConfig signingConfigs.release
          buildConfigField "String", "CODEPUSH_KEY", "\"wont-give-it\""

          minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
          proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
        release {
          signingConfig signingConfigs.release
          buildConfigField "String", "CODEPUSH_KEY", "\"wont-give-it\""

          minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
          proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
```

Please note that `releaseProduction` should contain `matchingFallbacks = ['release']`.

While this is working fine, it does not satisfy me. Why does `assembleReleaseStaging` pass, and `assembleRelease` fail?

Comment: This worked as well, but the reason is unknown for me: https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/4376#issuecomment-452678888

Comment: using `./gradlew app:assembleRelease` as mentioned in https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/4376#issuecomment-452678888 worked for me as well